# How can I make javascript apply to list of elements?

Tags: javascript, html, django

I want to flip cards in the browser. The elements are rendered with a Django template for loop. I'm able to flip the first card, but not the rest. I want them to flip individually.

Here's html:

```
   {% for element in elements %}
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">

          <div class="card-back">
            <span>{{ content }}</span>
          </div>

          <div class="card-front">
            <span>{{ content }}</span>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    {% endear %}
```

Here's javascript:

```
# works for the first element
var card = document.querySelector('.inner');
card.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
  card.classList.toggle('is-flipped');
});

# this function seems to break things
function() {
  var cards = document.querySelectorAll(".inner");
  for ( var i  = 0, len = cards.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    var card = cards[i];
    clickListener(card);
  }
});
```

Comment: What does `clickListener()` do and what errors are thrown in browser console? Those error messages are important clues. Note that `function () { })` is invalid syntax and would not ever get called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), `document.querySelector()` returns an `Element` object representing the first element that matches the specified set of CSS selectors, or `null` is if there are no matches.

This is why it works only for the first element.

If you want to apply this on all elements, you can use jQuery and register the event when the page is fully loaded.

```
<head>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js">

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $(".inner").on('click', function(event)
            {
                var card = event.target;
                card.classList.toggle('is-flipped');
            });
        });

    </script>

</head>
```

**IMPORTANT** : You don't need the function with the `for` loop, as jQuery will automatically apply the click event whenever a new element is added.

Comment: Still not working. I think your code works all except the event.target part. Doesn't seem to be calling anything. When I replace that with var card = document.querySelector('.inner'); clicking any card will flip the first one. So it's close...

Comment: When you run my code, is there any warnings/errors in console ? Because I tested it in my computet and its working fine

Comment: Ah ok I got it. Instead of this: card.classList.toggle('is-flipped'); I used              this.classList.toggle('is-flipped'); and it worked. Thanks Amine.